# CSS container placement

Tags: html, css, css-position

I would like to use this template for my project: https://codepen.io/albizan/pen/mMWdWZ (background-image url is not valid anymore). The problem is, I am not able to place a container to some position on the home page. I tried many CSS options but navbar is moved relatively (here by 300&200px). Any idea?

`.container {position: relaive; left: 300px; top: 200px;}`

Comment: use `margin-left` instead of `left` property

Comment: It doesn't solve this problem

Comment: you have a typo there  *position: relaive*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to give position absolute to a navbar. So that container sizing does not affect the navbar.And MIstake "relative" spelling.

Comment: It is OK now. The problem was, that I overlooked, that navbar also uses container. So the offset was applied on both. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
.container {
  position: relative;
  left: 300px;
  top: 200px;
}
```

Use like this way.

Comment: If not Work let me know.